# How to use a custom sql query in Apache Superset

Tags: sql, apache-superset

I would like to know when creating a chart how to use the custom sql option. My data are a *city* field and an *electricity consumption* field. I create a *Big Number* chart > i click on metric > custom sql. I enter this code:

```
SELECT City, SUM(`Conso (MWh)`) AS TotalConso
FROM table1 
GROUP BY City
ORDER BY TotalConso ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

And I get this error: *Unexpected error Error: Custom SQL fields cannot contain sub-queries.*

Answer (score 1):

> creating a bar chart with a custom SQL field that shows the city with the highest electricity consumption

I think you can try this sql query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table AS
SELECT City, SUM(`Conso (MWh)`) AS TotalConso
FROM table1
GROUP BY City
ORDER BY TotalConso DESC
LIMIT 1;

SELECT City, TotalConso
FROM tmp_table;
```

Comment: Hello, I wanted a kpi indicating the city that consumes the most. So in bar char i clicked to metric and add the code in custom sql, i have the same problem